# If one chants a Vishnu mantra does he need to chant Lakshmi mantra too to attain grace of mata Lakshmi?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi, vedic-chanting

Maa Lakshmi is the wife of Lord Vishnu. If one chants Vishnu mantra, does he receives blessings of mata Lakshmi too? Are things related to this mentioned in Puranas? Is chanting Vishnu mantra bestowes one with wealth and salvation too? Any scriptural references?

Comment: There is a footnote to the story of Bhrigu kicking Lord Vishnu:Mother Lakshmi gave a curse to all Brahmins to be poor,in her sheer anger,but later she relented and said that Brahmins can  be rich if they worship Lord Vishnu.(This is something I heard,though)